# Remove attributes and values from XML when it matches the given key

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have to remove a few fields from the XML payload. I wrote a function below but it is checks and removes only the keys.

How to apply the condition also to attributes and values?

Basically, it has remove whereever the fields are available like tag/value/attributes

**Sample Input**

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml skipNullOn="everywhere"
%function remove(content, filterList)
    content match {
        :array -> $ map (value,index) -> remove(value, filterList),
        :object -> $ mapObject (value,key) ->
            (key) @((key.@)) : null when (filterList contains key as :string)
                otherwise remove(value, filterList)
            ,
        default -> content
    }
---
remove(payload, ["userId","companyId","account"])
```

Comment: Please provide an example input, actual output and expected output.

Comment: @aled have updated the question.TIA!

Comment: Is the output that you added the expected output or actual output?

Comment: @aled it is the expected output. you could see few tags and attributes were removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input is not a valid XML, I have updated to make it valid. The following Dataweave removes all attribute name/value and tag/value matching the filter list.

Note that in the output attribute `type` is removed because the value matches `account`

Input

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:test="http://host.com2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns6="http://host.com/V001">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <axis2ns11343:OSARequestHeader xmlns:axis2ns11343="http://www.host.com/xmlschema/resource/metadata/osa/infrastructure/v001" soapenv:mustUnderstand="false">
            <axis2ns11343:userId>e2eauto01a</axis2ns11343:userId>
            <axis2ns11343:companyId>test</axis2ns11343:companyId>
            <axis2ns11343:companyType/>
            <axis2ns11343:clientMachineId>1.1.1.1</axis2ns11343:clientMachineId>
        </axis2ns11343:OSARequestHeader>
        <axis2ns11344:cpsMessageHeader xmlns:axis2ns11344="http://host.com/xsd/types/V002" type="currency" guid="28cd611f-2e08-4650-8217-cdd27284968f" soapenv:mustUnderstand="false" traceId="28cd611f-2e08-4650-8217-cdd27284968f"/>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns8:getCurrencyProfileRequest xmlns:ns8="http://host.com/xsd/service/V001" accType ="code" username="username" type="account">
            <ns8:userInfo>
                <ns3:type xmlns:ns3="http://host.com/xsd/commontypes/V001">accountNo</ns3:type>
                <ns3:companyId xmlns:ns3="http://host.com/xsd/commontypes/V001">string</ns3:companyId>
                <ns3:userId xmlns:ns3="http://host.com/xsd/commontypes/V001">string</ns3:userId>
                <ns3:accountNo xmlns:ns3="http://host.com/xsd/commontypes/V001">string</ns3:accountNo>
                <ns3:txid xmlns:ns3="http://host.com/xsd/commontypes/V001">string</ns3:txid>
            </ns8:userInfo>
        </ns8:getCurrencyProfileRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml skipNullOn="everywhere"

%function checkAndRemoveAttributes (attribs, filterList)
 (attribs default {}) mapObject {
    ($$): null when (filterList contains ($$ as :string)) otherwise $
 }
  
%function remove(content, filterList)
    content match {
        :object -> $ mapObject (value,key) ->
            (key) @((checkAndRemoveAttributes(key.@,filterList))): null when (filterList contains key as :string)
                otherwise remove(value, filterList)
            ,
        default -> null when (filterList contains content as :string) otherwise content
    }
---
remove(payload, ["userId","companyId","account","username", "code"])
```

Output

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='US-ASCII'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <axis2ns11343:OSARequestHeader xmlns:axis2ns11343="http://www.host.com/xmlschema/resource/metadata/osa/infrastructure/v001" soapenv:mustUnderstand="false">
      <axis2ns11343:companyType></axis2ns11343:companyType>
      <axis2ns11343:clientMachineId>1.1.1.1</axis2ns11343:clientMachineId>
    </axis2ns11343:OSARequestHeader>
    <axis2ns11344:cpsMessageHeader xmlns:axis2ns11344="http://host.com/xsd/types/V002" type="currency" guid="28cd611f-2e08-4650-8217-cdd27284968f" soapenv:mustUnderstand="false" traceId="28cd611f-2e08-4650-8217-cdd27284968f"></axis2ns11344:cpsMessageHeader>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns8:getCurrencyProfileRequest xmlns:ns8="http://host.com/xsd/service/V001" accType="code" type="account">
      <ns8:userInfo>
        <ns3:type xmlns:ns3="http://host.com/xsd/commontypes/V001">accountNo</ns3:type>
        <ns3:accountNo xmlns:ns3="http://host.com/xsd/commontypes/V001">string</ns3:accountNo>
        <ns3:txid xmlns:ns3="http://host.com/xsd/commontypes/V001">string</ns3:txid>
      </ns8:userInfo>
    </ns8:getCurrencyProfileRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: if the input has multiple attributes. it is not working.

Comment: Please provide more details. What is not working? Perhaps, an input that doesn't work will help narrow down the issue..

Comment: have updated the question with sample input. the issue here is if a tag has multiple attribute values it is outputting the XML with only one attribute remaining attributes are not preserved.

Comment: I was going by the original post- `Basically, it has remove whereever the fields are available like tag/value/attributes`. The code removes matching attribute/tag name& value. As you have added `account` and `code` to the filter list, it removes the attributes with values matching the filter. But seems like you don't want to remove the matching attribute value. I have updated the code by removing the attribute value filter condition.